# How does bitcoin impact the real economy?

Tags: shrinking-money-supply

I have a question in my head since a while.

What if Elon Musk sells all his companies (spacex, Tesla, ...) and puts all the money in bitcoin and then loses the keys. What is going to happen to the real economy?

Comment: Hi dmx, we already have a few questions that are very similar to this one. Is your question answered by one of these? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/50497/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41744/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/1638/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/62112/5406

Comment: If Musk sells his companies, the companies (and their assets) still exist.  If he loses his private keys, the blockchain still exists.  Aside from the possibility that the new owners of the companies cannot replicate some unique skills belonging to Musk, why would you expect anything to change?

Answer (score -1):

I think bitcoin is like a knife, it can be used for both cooking and killing. If you say I use it for cooking, it does not mean that others do not use it to kill.
Terrorist groups, spy agencies and even criminal groups are all abusing Bitcoin.